# Django first migration has one anonymous user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model

When setting up a django project, the first time I run `manage.py migrate` and go to `manage.py shell` and run:

```
from users.models import User
users = User.objects.all()
users
[<User: AnonymousUser>]
```

I always get this `AnonymousUser`. After creating my superuser and checking on the admin page I get:

[image]

Does Django create this lonely `AnonymousUser` for a specific purpose, or am I configuring something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert here but looking through the [django auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests), it seems as though django creates this user to handle apps where users can choose not to authenticate and still interact with app in some level.

> If the current user has not logged in, this attribute [request.user] will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise it will be an instance of User.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Precisely, I haven't found the migration implementation on the source code, but it's a good surprise to see this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue with django-guardian, this apps creates AnonymousUser in the first migrate.

The docs says:

> GUARDIAN_GET_INIT_ANONYMOUS_USER
>     New in version 1.2.
>     Guardian supports object level permissions for anonymous users, however when in 
>     our project we use custom User model, default function might fail. This can lead 
>     to issues as guardian tries to create anonymous user after each syncdb call. 
>     Object that is going to be created is retrieved using function pointed by this 
>     setting. Once retrieved, save method would be called on that instance.
>     Defaults to "guardian.management.get_init_anonymous_user".